# How can I start multiple WebSocket connection concurrently?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, websocket, gunicorn

I have five different WebSocket endpoints that I'm serving in `gunicorn` with `uvicorn` via `django-channels` with this command.

It is run via a Docker container:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "-w", "4", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "config.asgi:application"]
```

I have some JavaScript that simply opens WebSocket connections to those endpoints:

```
const websocketUrl = 'http://example.com';

new WebSocket(`${websocketUrl}/ws/typeahead/foapal/`);
new WebSocket(`${websocketUrl}/ws/typeahead/fund/`);
new WebSocket(`${websocketUrl}/ws/typeahead/orgn/`);
new WebSocket(`${websocketUrl}/ws/typeahead/prog/`);
new WebSocket(`${websocketUrl}/ws/typeahead/actv/`);
```

What I want to happen is that all 5 of the connections above will open asynchronously. However, here's what it looks like in Chrome DevTools' Network tab:

[image: Network tab]

As you can see, the browser waits for one WebSocket connection be established before moving on to the next one.

How can I concurrently make those connections?

Comment: WebSockets don't block. This is most likely Django-channels not responding after the HTTP connection has been completed successfully.

Comment: Should I post my django-channels code, or is that part of the design of the asgi server?